# Can Node run multiple file read streams parallel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I am trying to:

1. receive a list of file paths
2. iterate over them and return an array of promises that start a stream for each file
3. pipe the stream to hash function
4. pipe to chunk gatherer that resolves the promise with derived hash value on end event

My setup works perfect with a single path and file, but with multiple paths and files I get false results.

It seems that file read stream is shared between all promise instances. I would like it to open a separate stream for each file, and resolve them when all streams are finished.

Is it compatible with how node streams work in general? Also, I am pretty sure that everything after the first `fs.createReadStream` is not relevant to the problem.

```
const fs = require("fs-extra")
const { Transform } = require("stream")
const hash = require("crypto")
  .createHash("sha256")
  .setEncoding("hex")

module.exports = {
  async start({ filePath }) {
    const hashes = await Promise.all(
      filePath.map(path => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          fs.createReadStream(path)
            .pipe(hash)
            .pipe(
              (() => {
                const data = []
                return new Transform({
                  transform(chunk, encoding, done) {
                    data.push(chunk)
                    done()
                  },
                  flush(done) {
                    resolve(data.toString())
                    done()
                  },
                })
              })()
            )
        })
      })
    )
    console.log(hashes)
  },
}
```

Comment: `but with multiple paths and files I get false results` , what do you mean by "false results" ?

Comment: I don't know what results you're expecting but I would assume you want to digest contents of multiple files in parallel. Well, if that's the case, you are most likely getting false results because you naively push data *from multiple files* into one and the same digest stream (`hash`). That won't work, if you think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing wrong with your example is that you are only creating one `hash` stream. All the files will go through the same stream so all the files will report the same hash. The below example creates a new hash stream for every file.

```
const fs = require("fs-extra");
const { Transform } = require("stream");
const hash = require("crypto");

module.exports = {
  async start({ filePath }) {
    const hashes = await Promise.all(
      filePath.map(path => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          fs.createReadStream(path)
            .pipe(hash.createHash("sha256").setEncoding("hex"))
            .pipe(
              (() => {
                const data = [];
                return new Transform({
                  transform(chunk, encoding, done) {
                    data.push(chunk);
                    done();
                  },
                  flush(done) {
                    resolve(data.toString());
                    done();
                  }
                });
              })()
            );
        });
      })
    );
    console.log(hashes);
  }
};
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I was so concentrated debugging the file stream, that I did not even notice that hash was reused for all files.

Answer (score 3):

So `fs` and `crypto` library are presented by `libuv` - one of the core parts of `nodejs`. These two libraries provide blocking operations and run them in separate threads. So if your processor has enough cores to manage a lot of operations in the one time you can easily run a lot of parallel processes. For example if your processor has 2 cores you can run 2 parallel read file streams

Comment: Considering how my question was worded, you answered most accurately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use async npm for this.

```
async.map(['file1','file2','file3'], fs.stat, function(err, results) {
    // results is now an array of stats for each file
});

async.filter(['file1','file2','file3'], function(filePath, callback) {
  fs.access(filePath, function(err) {
    callback(null, !err)
  });
}, function(err, results) {
    // results now equals an array of the existing files
});

async.parallel([
    function(callback) { ... },
    function(callback) { ... }
], function(err, results) {
    // optional callback
});

async.series([
    function(callback) { ... },
    function(callback) { ... }
]);
```